# In TypeScript, how do I create a number union from an array within a Record

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I have a Record like this:

```
const entityTypeExemptPayeeCodeMap: Record<EntityType, readonly PayeeCode[]> = {
  [EntityType.Smllc]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12],
  [EntityType.Llc]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12],
  [EntityType.CCorp]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12],
  [EntityType.SCorp]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12],
  [EntityType.Partnership]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12],
  [EntityType.TrustEstate]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13],
  [EntityType.Other]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13],
} as const;
```

I'd like to get a number union type from one of the arrays inside the Record. I thought this may work:

```
type SmllcExemptPayeeCodes = typeof entityTypeExemptPayeeCodeMap[EntityType.Smllc]
```

But that just gives me a type of `readonly PayeeCode[]` and not a union of the values in the array.

If I make `entityTypeExemptPayeeCodeMap` not be a Record, like this:

```
const entityTypeExemptPayeeCodeMap = {
  [EntityType.Smllc]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12],
  [EntityType.Llc]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12],
  [EntityType.CCorp]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12],
  [EntityType.SCorp]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12],
  [EntityType.Partnership]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12],
  [EntityType.TrustEstate]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13],
  [EntityType.Other]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13],
} as const;
```

then `SmllcExemptPayeeCodes` becomes a union as I would expect. Is there any way to keep the Record type for `entityTypeExemptPayeeCodeMap` and still retrieve a union?

In the above examples, EntityType is:

```
enum EntityType {
  Smllc = "smllc",
  Llc = "llc",
  CCorp = "cCorp",
  SCorp = "sCorp",
  Partnership = "partnership",
  TrustEstate = "trustEstate",
  Other = "other",
}
```

PayeeCode is:

```
type PayeeCode = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13;
```

Comment: Ah! I should have realized `PayeeCode` was a number literal union. :-) Thanks for adding those!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought this may work:
>
> ```
> type SmllcExemptPayeeCodes = typeof entityTypeExemptPayeeCodeMap[EntityType.Smllc]
> ```

...

> If I make `entityTypeExemptPayeeCodeMap` not be a `Record`, like this:...then `SmllcExemptPayeeCodes` becomes a union as I would expect.

That's odd, I'd expect you to need `[number]` on that.

> Is there any way to keep the Record type for `entityTypeExemptPayeeCodeMap` and still retrieve a union?

I don't think so, TypeScript will defer to what you've told it; but you can use an intermediate variable (`codeMap` in this example):

```typescript
const codeMap = {
    [EntityType.Smllc]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12],
    [EntityType.Llc]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12],
    [EntityType.CCorp]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12],
    [EntityType.SCorp]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12],
    [EntityType.Partnership]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12],
    [EntityType.TrustEstate]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13],
    [EntityType.Other]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13],
} as const;
const entityTypeExemptPayeeCodeMap: Record<EntityType, readonly PayeeCode[]> = codeMap;

type SmllcExemptPayeeCodes = (typeof codeMap)[EntityType.Smllc][number];
//   ^? type SmllcExemptPayeeCodes = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 11 | 12
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAoiAuBLeBPAKigDsKBvAUFEVAMoQA25AxlALxQBEAzhdQwDSHEAy1djlKhy5EAwqID2AJ0z8GVSTOHFSi2fWZrlxAAoBDKfBDApTABaJ1jTAaMnzl7UTRSwTeDHd74ODfFfunvDewE5QAPLwZiZyElEmwgC++Pio2FD6KMDAkgAmvlAAjFAAPlAATKVQAMxVACxVAKxVAGxVAOxVABxVAJxVhQAMA8VlhZVj1QDcKVQSIO5Qc-kAsnpWBCoA2nBIqBjYAHRkggC6AFxQW4XsFbfVt3W3Lbftt4U3ReWnnNu7yOgsMBDrwqBcrp9yvdHs9Xu9PuMfiIrv99kDDuJpJhwddblCajCoI1YVA3lBevD3t9fsQdggAQdgSQ1DjIdCoE8iSSyRSigjqci6XtAUd9IZjKYLNjLri7gSOdzKV8kX96Wiji43B4vD5WXj2ZyXqTbl13oMleN3tUVbTUSLgZFolI9XKHgqoEayaaiua+VSrUjElA9EwlvN3DM5gt4FBQMLGTAAB7ACCYeCZbJ5YBrTCXABKwDmUlyAB47YzblJgHpcvNyCgMnosjkJPktqcAHz8ZbZ9YzVJA0isKhJlNpjMt-Kh+gACjSwAkADMw6t1gBKIUM9EnainLbgCAAIxMpxmAHoz8QAHoAfiAA)

Then if you want things to only use the `Record` version, only expose `entityTypeExemptPayeeCodeMap` to other code and not `codeMap`.

Comment: You're right, I needed `[number]`. Thank you for confirming I can't pull the union directly from Record.